# find names/text that end with certain pattern (using BASE R)

Tags: r

I'm trying to find all variables names that end with "DE".

I'm already using this "grep" to find variables that start with "TR"

```
names(df )[ grep( "^(TR)" ,  names(df) ) ]
```

Is there a grep way to find the end pattern.
Just an fyi, I know I can do it with "ends_with" but I'm trying to find a base r method.

```
names( df %>% select(ends_with( "DE" ) ) )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already `endsWith` in `base R`

```
names(df)[endsWith(names(df), "DE")]
```

-a reproducible example

```
> names(iris)[endsWith(names(iris), "Length")]
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Petal.Length"
```

---

Or with `grep` use the `$` to specify the end of the string (also, with `grep`, we can use `value = TRUE` which returns the names instead of the numeric index

```
grep("DE$", names(df), value = TRUE)
# similar to
names(df)[grep("DE$", names(df)]
```

Or in a `base R` pipe

```
grep("DE$", names(df)) |>
   `[`(names(df), i = _)
grep("Length", names(iris)) |> 
  `[`(names(iris), i = _)
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Petal.Length"
```